# Method that excepts objects of derived class

Tags: c#

In the below example, I can add have a `List` of type `Animal`. Since `Dog` and `Cat` derive from animal, the `List` can hold each. However, if I have a method that accepts `List<Animal>`, you can not pass in a reference `List<Dog>`. If `Dog` is derived from animal, why is this not valid? However if i have a method that excepts a parameter of type `Object`, and all objects derive from `Object`, it works.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
       animals.Add(new Dog() { Color = "Black" }); // allowed since Dog derives from Animal

       List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
       dogs.Add(new Dog() { Color = "White" });

       Test(animals);
       Test(dogs); // not allowed - does not compile
       Test2(dogs); // valid as all objects derive from object
    }

    static void Test(List<Animal> animals) {
        // do something
    }

    static void Test2(object obj) { 

    }
}

public class Animal {

   public String Color { get; set; }

}

public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

Comment: Try `static void Test(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)`

Comment: search for `covariance and contravariance in c#`

Comment: As Selman22 suggests, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Sounds like the answer. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @PhilVallone Added to my existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that `Test(dogs)` *did* compile. Then imagine that `Test()` is implemented like follows:

```
static void Test(List<Animal> animals)
{
    animals.Add(new Cat()); // Where Cat is derived from Animal
}
```

You've just added a cat to a list of dogs... Clearly that can't be allowed. And that's why it's not.

However, if you are only accessing the elements of the list rather than adding to the list, you can declare `Test()` like so:

```
static void Test(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        // Do something with animal.
    }
}
```

Then you can pass any collection type which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, such as `List<T>` and plain arrays.

Comment: That makes a lot sense now.

Comment: Well, adding a cat to dogs usually is hilarious, so I'd allow it... ;)

Comment: Dogs and Cats... in the same `List<Animal>` ... [Mass Hysteria!!!](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9S4cldkdCjE&ei=vZfsVI6mL-bHsQSBuYDgCw&usg=AFQjCNGzPe3S7AsY6QTfnKAu-096C6WMcQ&sig2=9ik5utUb2D5HjVV7AOZ8jw&bvm=bv.86475890,d.cGU)

Comment: Depending on the usage: IReadOnlyCollection<T> is covariant. You should be able to pass that as a parameter. It -knows- you're not going to add items.

Comment: @Caramiriel True, but in that case it might be better to use `IEnumerable<T>` which works with more collection types. (Note that if you're using .Net 4 or earlier, you can't use `IReadOnlyCollection`.)

Answer (score 2):

Call `Test(dogs.Cast<Animal>().ToList())`. Change parameter type to IEnumerable to skip `ToList()` which creates a copy.

`int` is an `object`. `List<Animal>` is an `object`, as is `List<Dog>`. But `List<Dog>` is NOT `List<Animal>`.